# Sending excel objects to subroutines

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

As it is right now I have a bit of code that kind of looks like this (a little paraphrased but Im sure you get the idea)

```
   If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        swEV2.Stop()
        If ComboBox3.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
            xlWorkSheet202.Activate()
            xlWorkSheet202.Cells((AT + 2), 3) = TextBox1.Text
            xlWorkSheet202.Cells((AT + 3), 2) = "PSS (kBs)"
            xlWorkSheet202.Cells((AT + 3), 3) = "USS (kBs)"
            xlWorkSheet202.Cells((AT + 3), 4) = "User %"
            xlWorkSheet202.Cells((AT + 3), 5) = "Kernel %"
            xlWorkSheet202.Cells((AT + 3), 6) = "Total %"
            xlWorkSheet202.Cells((AT + 4), 1) = "Min:"
            xlWorkSheet202.Cells((AT + 5), 1) = "Max:"
            xlWorkSheet202.Cells((AT + 6), 1) = "Average:"
            xlWorkSheet202.Cells((AT + 7), 1) = "Median:"
            xlWorkSheet202.Cells((AT + 8), 1) = "Stan Dev:"
        ElseIf ComboBox3.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
            xlWorkSheet204.Cells((WT + 2), 3) = TextBox1.Text
            xlWorkSheet204.Cells((WT + 3), 2) = "PSS (kBs)"
            xlWorkSheet204.Cells((WT + 3), 3) = "USS (kBs)"
            xlWorkSheet204.Cells((WT + 3), 4) = "User %"
            xlWorkSheet204.Cells((WT + 3), 5) = "Kernel %"
            xlWorkSheet204.Cells((WT + 3), 6) = "Total %"
            xlWorkSheet204.Cells((WT + 4), 1) = "Min:"
            xlWorkSheet204.Cells((WT + 5), 1) = "Max:"
            xlWorkSheet204.Cells((WT + 6), 1) = "Average:"
            xlWorkSheet204.Cells((WT + 7), 1) = "Median:"
            xlWorkSheet204.Cells((WT + 8), 1) = "Stan Dev:"
```

This goes on 3 more times in a few different places... So now I am trying to refactor the code to make it cleaner and shorter.

What I would like to do is this:

```
  If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        swEV2.Stop()
        If ComboBox3.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
            Excelupdate(xlWorkSheet203, AT)
        ElseIf ComboBox3.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
            Excelupdate(xlWorkSheet204, WT)

    Private sub ExcelUpdate(byref worksheet as object, byref update as string)

        worksheet.Activate()
        worksheet.Cells((update + 2), 3) = TextBox1.Text
        worksheet.Cells((update + 3), 2) = "PSS (kBs)"
        worksheet.Cells((update + 3), 3) = "USS (kBs)"
        worksheet.Cells((update + 3), 4) = "User %"
        worksheet.Cells((update + 3), 5) = "Kernel %"
        worksheet.Cells((update + 3), 6) = "Total %"
        worksheet.Cells((update + 4), 1) = "Min:"
        worksheet.Cells((update + 5), 1) = "Max:"
        worksheet.Cells((update + 6), 1) = "Average:"
        worksheet.Cells((update + 7), 1) = "Median:"
        worksheet.Cells((update + 8), 1) = "Stan Dev:"
     end sub
```

I thought for sure the above would work but it still seems that I am missing something, when I open the excel sheet nothing was printed. This would cut down the lines of code that I have in half easily, so I would love to find a solution for this

Thanks Guys

.......................................................

Edit (Sorry those comment boxes are terrible for writing anything)

.......................................................

alright I tried changing these lines of code:

```
        If ComboBox2.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
            If ComboBox3.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
                ExcelUpdate(xlWorkSheet202, AT, CDbl(Pvalue), CDbl(uvalue), CDbl(UserRx.Match(line).Value), CDbl(KernelRx.Match(line).Value))
            ElseIf ComboBox3.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
                ExcelUpdate(xlWorkSheet203, GT, CDbl(Pvalue), CDbl(uvalue), CDbl(UserRx.Match(line).Value), CDbl(KernelRx.Match(line).Value))
            ElseIf ComboBox3.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
                ExcelUpdate(xlWorkSheet204, WT, CDbl(Pvalue), CDbl(uvalue), CDbl(UserRx.Match(line).Value), CDbl(KernelRx.Match(line).Value))
            ElseIf ComboBox3.SelectedIndex = 3 Then
                ExcelUpdate(xlWorkSheet205, OT, CDbl(Pvalue), CDbl(uvalue), CDbl(UserRx.Match(line).Value), CDbl(KernelRx.Match(line).Value))
            End If
        End If

Private Sub ExcelUpdate(ByVal Sheet As Object, ByVal update As Integer, ByVal pval As Double, ByVal uval As Double, ByVal user As Double, ByVal kernel As Double)
    update = update + 1
    Sheet.cells(update, 1) = timenow
    Sheet.cells(update, 2) = pval
    Sheet.cells(update, 3) = uval
    Sheet.cells(update, 4) = user
    Sheet.cells(update, 5) = kernel
    Sheet.cells(update, 6) = cdbl(kernel + User)
 end sub
```

But the excel sheets still do not update with the new information. Is there anything else im missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check/change a couple of things:

1) Change the ByRefs in the function to ByVal. You don't need to update the reference to the worksheet or modify the string, so ByRef is not need.

2) Determine the data type of the update parameter. You are mixing operation and types, which could result in an incorrect cells reference.

If the goal of the cell reference is:

```
worksheet.Cells(("A2"), 3)
```

then you should change your code to:

```
worksheet.Cells((update & "2"), 3)
```

If the goal of the cell reference is:

```
worksheet.Cells((12), 3)
```

then you should change the update parameter type:

```
update as integer
```

Comment: Whats the difference between a byval and a byref, and when would I use a byref? and The goal is "12" so I will try changing that to integer

Comment: Passing the argument ByRef means that the procedure can modify the variable that was passed in. For objects, this means you could set the value to Nothing or create a new instance. For strings, it means you can change the value of the string and it will go back to the caller. ByVal means you pass the object by value. For objects, you can change or access properties within the object, but not the object reference itself. For strings, it means that you can change the string all you want in the procedure, but it won't affect the variable in the caller's scope.

Comment: I posted an *edit* to the original code in the above question box, I think its easier to write code up there vs in the comment box

Comment: Ok I figured it out, I had the wrong combobox listed : P Thanks!